# How to capture from capture card?

Tags: sound, video, capture

I am trying to capture video and audio from my VCR and I keep running into an issue. I go into VLC and click 'Media>Open Capture Device' and everything I select results in an error. The only thing that works is the antenna capture, and I can't get audio through THAT either. I have a Hauppauge WinTV PVR-150 card. What is happening, and how can I get this working? Thanks. Also, will it work better on an actual Ubuntu system?(not a stripped-down version)

P.S. I am using LXLE 14.04 or 14.10.

Comment: The actual errors would he helpful.

Comment: File reading failed:
VLC could not open the file "/home/the-computer-geek/hw:0,0" (No such file or directory).
VLC is unable to to open the MRL 'file:///home/the-computer-geek/hw%3A0%2C0'. Check the log for details.